# Casting primitive types

Tags: java

I investigated a lot about this but I didn't find an answer that convinces me; for that reason I decided to ask it here.

When you do casting, what occurs internally with the compiler?  For example:

```
double b= 5.67
a = (int) b
```

Does java convert the type of the variable or converts the internal value of?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "convert the type of the variable"? What observable difference are you asking about?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3 for the steps that the conversion goes through...

Comment: I ve read it. But thats why im asking here.  I don't know if the type of the variable changes or the inside value of the variable. I read even in some post and says the type of the value changes and in other post says the type of variable changes. So.... XD im confused

Comment: `b` obviously remains a `double` and doesn't change its type. `a` keeps its type too and is assigned an integer value

Comment: I'm not sure this is an exact duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676503/what-does-casting-do-at-compiler-machine-level) but it contains a lot of small pieces you may find interesting.

Comment: The cast does not change `b` in any way. `a` is assigned the value resulting from the evaluation of the expression `(int) b`, which  is described by the [JLS chapter "5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) already linked to

Comment: What type is `a`?

Comment: Assuming `a` is an `int`, it will convert the bit pattern stored in `b`, which is `0100000000010110101011100001010001111010111000010100011110101110`, into the bit pattern for 5, which is `00000000000000000000000000000101`, and store that in `a`.

Comment: "and in other post says the type of variable changes" - where? Variables *never* change their type. If you're confused by different materials, you should link to those materials rather than asking a somewhat vague question.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the Java compiler will prevent you from assigning primitives that might result in a loss of data. You don't make it clear, but I am assuming that `a` is an `int`. Assigning a `double` to an `int` can result in information being lost, so the compiler objects.

If you add a cast the compiler ignores the issue and adds code to do whatever is necessary to convert the value from one type to the value of the other (in this case, assuming `a` is an int, simply truncating the double in many cases) and ignores any data loss. The type of the variables remains unchanged. Only the value changes.

There is a bit more to it than that for certain values. For example, if the double has the special value `NaN` (not a number) it is converted to `int 0`. See in the Java Specification [5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).